# Undefined index notice for Smarty section loop

Tags: smarty

I am getting undefined index error for my section loop when the loop results no data or empty from MySQL database.

Code as follow:

```
{section name=foo loop=$data}
//data goes here
{/section}
```

How can I use isset() in section loop?

Am using smarty 3.1.21 version

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really try with `default` variable handling as mentioned [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/tips.default.var.handling.tpl)

```
{section name=foo loop=$data|defalut:""}
//data goes here
{/section}
```

or

If you are not using `{sectionelse}` then use this one.

```
{section name=foo loop=$data|defalut:"No data found"}
 //data goes here
{/section}
```

Hope this helps :)